# Change double sum limits

Tags: analysis, summation

I am trying to change a double sum limits but I am not sure if 
I am doing correctly. The sum is and my solution is

$\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{a^m\sqrt{(m+r)!}}{m!}=\sum_{r=0}^{m'}\sum_{m'=0}^\infty \frac{a^{m'-r}\sqrt{m'!}}{(m'-r)!};\quad with\quad  m'=m+r$

Currently, I am struggling to find the solution to an equation of which this double sum is part, and I think this double sum could be the problem. So I would be really grateful if some could help me to understand if my change of limits is correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the sum is not defined for m=0

Comment: Sorry, I changed that. A factorial was missing.

Comment: in the second sum $m'$ should start from $m'=r$

Comment: why did you change $\sum_{r=0}^n$ with $ \sum_{r=0}^{m'}$?

Comment: I did $ \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty \rightarrow \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{m'=r}^\infty \rightarrow \sum_{r=0}^{m'} \sum_{m'=0}^\infty$. This because I want to get rid of the second sum througth a kronecker delta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $m'=m+r$ we have that

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{a^m\sqrt{(m+r)!}}{m!}=\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{m'=r}^\infty \frac{a^{m'-r}\sqrt{m'!}}{(m'-r)!}$$